# how to setFont Arial and symbol on 1 cell in FPDF

Tags: symbols, fpdf

So, if I want to use a symbol, but there is a word behind the symbol, what should I do?
I wanted a look like this

> Σsum

, and this is what I've been trying to do ,,,

```
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
$this->SetX(10);
$this->Cell(5,10,'NO.',1,0,'C',1);
$this->SetFont('Symbol','B',7);
$this->SetX(15);
$this->Cell(15,10,"SUM".chr(83),1,0,'C',1);
```

Comment: You can use only one font in a Cell. If you really want to mix characters, consider using [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=92) with a font that contains all the characters you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code display what you're looking for.
(Note $pdf instead of $this)

```
$pdf->SetXY(10,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Symbol','B',7);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'S',0,'','C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);
$pdf->Cell(-3,10,'sum',0,'','C');
```